# Unexpected behaviour creating DialogFragment instance

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have this `android.app.DialogFragment`:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

   private Callback callback;

    public static MyDialog newInstance() {
      return new MyDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            //set more things
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                callback.run(); //callback is null        
            }).create();
        return dialog;
    }

    public void setCallback(Callback callback) { this.callback = callback; }

}
```

and from my activity:

```
MyDialog dialog = MyDialog.newInstance();
dialog.setCallback(myCallback);
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

But when I click "Ok" button, it crashes beacuse callback is `null`. **myCallback is never null**

I found something. `onCreateDialog` is called twice and the second time `callback` is `null`:

```
  @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("test", "onCreateDialog (" + this + ") -> " + callback);
        //more code
    }
```

It prints:

> onCreateDialog (MyDialog{18ea188e})
>   -> com.house.hehe.MyActivity$3@3afbe8af
>
> onCreateDialog (MyDialog{22199eaa})
>   -> null

How is it possible? Why are there two different instances? Why is `onCreateDialog` called twice?

Comment: can you post a stacktrace or indicate the line where your app crashes?

Comment: It crashes in `callback.run()` line, in the button listener.

Comment: try making Callback public and also this.callback.run() ;

Comment: Shouldn't `public class MyDialog` be `public static class MyDialog`?

Comment: @EricB. the first level public class in a java file can't be static

Comment: My bad, I thought it was some inner class.

Comment: What is the full class name of the Callback class?

Comment: It is a private inner static class inside MyDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is happening but I have solved by doing `callback` an static static:

private static Callback callback;

```
public static MyDialog newInstance(Callback callback) {
    MyDialog.callback = callback;      
    return new MyDialog();
}
```

It is an ugly solution... oh well...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set the callback as you would with a normal Fragment, set it in `onAttach(Context context)` and remove it in `onDetach()`